# Displaying objects as a choice inside a template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Right now my code looks like this:

```
#models.py
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')

class Course(models.Model):
    course_document = models.ForeignKey(Document,null=True,blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

#forms.py
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
docfile = forms.FileField(
    label='Select a file',
    help_text='max. 42 megabytes'
)
course = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Course.objects.all(),
                          widget=forms.RadioSelect)

#views.py
def list(request):
# Handle file upload
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
        newdoc.save()

        # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notes_app.views.list'))
else:
    form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

# Load documents for the list page
documents = Document.objects.all()

# Render list page with the documents and the form
return render_to_response(
    'notes_app/list.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)

#notes_app/list.html  -- The majority of it anyway

    <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.docfile.errors }}
            {{ form.docfile }}
        </p>
```

I used a simple python script to populate the "Courses" into the database, and want I want is so each time a User uploads a file they choose a "Course" and that course is associated with the file they uploaded, so my question is how do I display those courses as a choice? Sorry if this question seems stupid I am new to programming and even newer to python/django. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? do you get an error or what? Seems like you are doing right...

Comment: The problem is that I can't figure out how to display the courses as a choice for the user. All I am currently displaying is the option to upload a file.  So I don't know what I need to add in my view and/or template.

Comment: Is it empty or what?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still haven't really understood your question but this might help you.
In your models.py

```
course_name = ('English', 'Maths',)
from model_utils import Choices
class Course(models.Model):
    course_document = models.ForeignKey(Document,null=True,blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Choices(*course_name))
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

This will create a drop down menu for choosing courses.

Comment: yes this is what I want to do and part of the problem, I have a giant .txt file with a list of all the courses I want as a choice but I cant find a way to generate the tuples from the file for the choices, so I created a courses class and used a script to generate course objects and now I'm wondering if I can use those objects as a choice somehow.

Comment: I don't think so your your objects will have something like a ' 'course_name' attribute which will be equal to name of the course. If you try `print object` it will display something like `<Element 0x11..>` you can maybe use object.course_name as choices rather than the whole object itself.

Answer (score 0):

`choices` should be a `CharField`, with a choices argument.  The value of the choices argument is a `tuple` with 2 items in it. The first is a value for you to access if you need it. The second value is what the User sees.  So"

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    courses = forms.CharField(max_length=255, choices=(
        ('1', 'First Course'),
        ('2', 'Second Course')
        )
    )
```

Here is the Django Docs for this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices